# Processing semi-inhomogenous structured files with Spark (CSV, Parquet)

Tags: parquet, spark-csv

I have several inhomogenous structured files stored in a Hadoop cluster. The files contain a header line but not all files contain the same columns.

file1.csv:

```
a,b,c
1,2,1
```

file2.csv:

```
a,b,d
2,2,2
```

What I need to do is looking for all data in column a or column c and process it further (possibly Spark SQL). So I expect something like:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,1,,
2,2,,2
```

Just doing

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(CSV_PATH)
```

will miss all columns not present in the "first" file read.

How can I do this? Is a conversion to Parquet and its dataset feature a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Read two files separately and create a two dataframes. Then do an inner join between those two w.r.t join keys as a,b

Comment: This might work when done manully once in a while, but considering there will be hundreds if not thousands of GB-sized files I am looking for a smoother approach than joining everthing manually before looking at column b only (to stick with the example.

Comment: I am not talking about manual approach. That’s does not depend on the file size. Spark will handle for you only you need write query in spark sql w.r.t the join keys. You need to know your schema for the files if you want to achieve the desired result. Write your code in spark with Scala or python or java build a fat jar and deploy it to your server. Then do a spark submit. Even you can parameterize your file paths.